# Matplotlib legend numpoints don't work

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

I have such piece of code:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

mpl.rcParams['legend.numpoints'] = 1
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0., 1.02, 1., .102), loc=3,
           ncol=5, mode="expand", numpoints=1, borderaxespad=0.)
```

But it doesn't work. Quantity of poitns is still 3.
Any ideas?
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The legend handles in your figure with 3 points are from scatter plots. You can control them with the `scatterpoints` kwarg.

`numpoints` is used for objects created with `plt.plot`, not `plt.scatter`

```
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0., 1.02, 1., .102), loc=3,
           ncol=5, mode="expand", numpoints=1, borderaxespad=0., 
           scatterpoints=1)
```

Or

```
mpl.rcParams['legend.scatterpoints'] = 1
```